# Django: Cannout update model through form POST, only Shell

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x

**What are you trying to accomplish? (Please include sample data.)**

I am trying to create a form in Django that takes in data and saves them in a database.

**Paste the part of the code that shows the problem. (Please indent 4 spaces.)**

> index4.html

```
    <form action="post_url/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

> urls.py (project folder)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from exercises.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^numbers/', numbers, name="numbers"),
    url(r'^about/', about, name="about"),
    url(r'^post_url/$', post_treasure, name='post_treasure')
]
```

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Treasure
from .forms import TreasureForm

def numbers(request):
    treasures = Treasure.objects.all()
    form = TreasureForm()
    return render(request, 'index4.html', {'treasures': treasures, 'form':form})

def about(request):
    return render(request, "about.html", {})

def q1(request):
    return HttpResponse("What is the average age of a dinosaur?")

def post_treasure(request):
    form = TreasureForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        treasure = Treasure(name = form.cleaned_data['name'],
                            value = form.cleaned_data['value'],
                            material = form.cleaned_data['material'],
                            location = form.cleaned_data['location'],
                            img_url = form.cleaned_data['img_url'])
        treasure.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

> forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Treasure

# class TreasureForm(forms.ModelForm):
#   class Meta:
#       model = Treasure
#       fields = ['name', 'value', 'location', 'material']
#       if form.is_valid():
#           form.save(commit = True)
#       return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

class TreasureForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', max_length=100)
    value = forms.DecimalField(label='Value', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    material = forms.CharField(label='Material', max_length=100)
    location = forms.CharField(label='Location', max_length=100)
    img_url = forms.CharField(label='Image URL', max_length=100)
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Treasure(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**What do you expect the result to be? && What is the actual result you get? (Please include any errors.)**
After filling in the form, I expected the Treasure model class to contain a new Treasure object. This does not occur if I confirm it using the python shell, but also through the list of treasures on the index4.html template. The only way this works is if I manually add a Treasure using the python shell

Errors: N/A, program compiles successfully

Comment: Errors are still applicable in python. What happens at the moment when you click post? Do you get a run error or a 404 or does it post successfully?

Comment: If the below doesn't solve it, can you put a print statement after form.is_valid() to make sure it's passing?

Answer (score 1):

Change your form action in index.html to:

```
<form action="{% url 'post_treasure' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You should also consider going back to the modelform you were using. It's a better way to do this.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, new error

" File "/home/zzzz/Desktop/proj/src/exercises/views.py", line 26, in post_treasure
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
NameError: name 'HttpResponseRedirect' is not defined

Comment: just another update, it manages to save the data to the database (yay) but after I press submit the above error comes up so if I go back the page, it displays the newly added treasure object

Comment: You need to import HttpResponseRedirect before you can use it.